# Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: _alltemplates for indexable

Tags: indexing

Whenever I run `sitecore_master_index` or `sitecore_suggested_test_index` on `Sitecore 9.0.1`, I see the below errors in the `Crawling` logs. I cannot find the item `{7FBCE76B-D04A-42C9-8CB2-D61BFA202879}` in the `Content Tree` either.

Any suggestions please?

````
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Item template not found.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.IndexOperationsHelper.GetAllTemplates(Item item)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractDocumentBuilder`1.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<AddComputedIndexFieldsInParallel>b__0(IComputedIndexField computedIndexField, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had a template which was somehow removed from Sitecore later.

Or alternatively, one synchronized an item without synchronizing the template, and now you have an item in your database which has no template.

Solution? Run the following script on your SQL database:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[TemplateID]
      ,[ParentID]
  FROM [Items]
  WHERE [TemplateID] = '{7FBCE76B-D04A-42C9-8CB2-D61BFA202879}'
```

and for any `[ID]` from the result set open item in `dbbrowser` tool:

```
`https://yourhost/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx?db=master&lang=en&id=[ID]`
```

Delete that item.

If necessary, change database from `master` to e.g. `web` in the url above.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. The solution works :)